# Copy construction throughout inheritance chain

Tags: c++, c++11

Shouldn't the copy constructors be used instead throughout the inheritance chain?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
public:
     A(){ cout <<"1";}
     A(const A &obj){ cout <<"2";}
};

class B: virtual public A
{
public:
    B(){cout <<"3";}
    B(const B & obj){cout<<"4";}
};

class C: virtual public A
{
public:
   C(){cout<<"5";}
   C(const C & obj){cout <<"6";}
};

class D:B,C
{
public:
    D(){cout<<"7";}
    D(const D & obj){cout <<"8";}
};

int main()
{
   D d1;
   D d(d1);
}
```

Output:

```
13571358
```

Expected:

```
13572468
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The copy constructor is only used for `D`, because the `D` copy constructor does not call the copy constructors of its base classes.

It should be declared as

```
D(const D &obj): A(obj), B(obj), C(obj) {cout <<"8";}
```

unless I've mistyped something.

The `A` object needs to be copy constructed here since it is a virtual base class, which is constructed in the most derived class.

Comment: Thank you 1201ProgramAlarm.  That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 3):

> Wouldn't the copy constructors be used instead throughout the inheritance chain?

It will be if you leave the compiler to do it for you. Since you have defined it yourself, you need to do the right thing.

```
D(const D & obj){cout <<"8";}
```

is equivalent to:

```
D(const D & obj) : A(), B(), C() {cout <<"8";}
```

You need to use:

```
D(const D & obj) : A(obj), B(obj), C(obj) {cout <<"8";}
```

to make sure that copy constructors of the base classes are called.

Comment: R Sahu, thank you for your clear explanation.  I gave the points to 1201 because he posted first and he said mostly the same thing.  I up voted you.